# Get all objects from array that matches string key using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
const eoSc2 = {
    "eo": {
        "N": [{sc: "CT"}, {sc: "PRS"}],
        "PDO": [{sc: "CRF"}, {sc: "CPF"}],
    }
};

const key = "N";
```

I'm trying to get the array that match to `key` value.

```
var keys = Object.keys(eoSc2.eo); //get keys from object as an array

keys.filter( (key) =>  { //loop through keys array
  return key === eo
});
```

Not working

Comment: Almost there, eo must be a string `"eo"`, I suppose the variable `eo` is not defined anywhere. Also note that there can be only be one key `"eo"` and that you can access it directly with `eoSc2["eo"] or eoSc2.eo`

Comment: you are trying to compare the key with eo, instead do 'eo'. Also keys of 'eo' will not include eo itself but N and PDO, so comparison key == 'eo' will not match.

Comment: Why `.filter()` at all? `const val = eoSc2.eo[key]`. It's either `undefined` or what ever is stored under that key.

Comment: I'm trying to get `[{sc: "CT"}, {sc: "PRS"}]`by the way

Comment: @Andreas LOL, yes

Comment: Object.values(eoSc2.eo.N) - This will do the job

Comment: @Tick20 There's no need for `Object.values`

Comment: It is working but there is no `eo` key inside of `{"N": [{sc: "CT"}, {sc: "PRS"}], "PDO": [{sc: "CRF"}, {sc: "CPF"}], }`

Comment: @Juan Mendes, you are correct.

Comment: Can you show an example of input and desired output?

Comment: I don't know why you're looking for something that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess:

```js
const eoSc2 = {
    "eo": {
        "N": [{sc: "CT"}, {sc: "PRS"}],
        "PDO": [{sc: "CRF"}, {sc: "CPF"}],
    }
};

const key = "N";

const keys = eoSc2['eo'][key]

console.log(keys)
```